# Dump stack to array

Tags: tips, cjam

I'm new to this code-golfing thing and I'm very interested in CJam.

Is there a way to get all the current stack as an array? I think I can do it with something like `[1$ 2$...n$]` but I would have to get the stack's length and use some kind of iterator (or use a fixed length stack... useless). But is there a way to achieve this with a single operator?
The thing is I want to iterate over all the stack's elements.

Sorry if the question is obvious or seems stupid, but I'm new to this and I couldn't find anything...

Comment: `or use a fixed length stack... useless` Oftentimes you do know how many items are going to be on the stack at a given time.

Comment: This would probably be more on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Challenger5 Tips questions in general are perfectly on topic here. While *some* esoteric languages have found a way to SO, I doubt CJam questions would be well-received.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is covered on https://cjam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, which you'll probably find useful if you're interested in learning CJam. By the way, once you earn 20 reputation, you'll be able to join us in chat. Simple questions like this one will be answered quickly in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: @Dennis Thanks. (That 11 below my username is actually my reputation, isn't it? idk I don't really understand how all this StackExchange thing work)

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also see your reputation in [your profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69760/iaka-noe).

Comment: @Dennis What do you mean by *well-recieved*? AFAIK it's on-topic, but I don't think it would be answered.

Comment: @Challenger5 Get downvoted or, worse, left unanswered. If it's unlikely to get answered on SO, there really is no reason to post it there.

Comment: @Dennis What happened to the [esoteric] tag?

Comment: @Challenger5 Mind joining me in TNB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unmatched `]` command will make the entire stack into an array.

```
1 2 3 4 ] -> [1 2 3 4]
```